# Navigating interviews for 2 different roles in the same firm?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, multiple-jobs

I'm interviewing for 2 different roles in different teams and geographies but the same firm. The first one, I'm expecting the offer letter soon. The interviews for the other are still ongoing and will likely take a month. This role is slightly more preferred by me.

I want to understand if I should mention to each team about the other (in my experience firms just shut shop to you in case of any special circumstances so I'm not keen on this).

More importantly, How should I ask the other team to speed up their process politely without potentially ruining my chances with them?

Comment: Tell the hiring manager of the second team, the one you're waiting on and the one you prefer, the truth. That will speed things up. That's really the easiest solution. You can't really control the outcome of what's going to happen either way.

Answer (score 4):

> The first one, I'm expecting the offer letter soon. The interviews for
> the other are still ongoing and will likely take a month. This role is
> slightly more preferred by me.

Don't talk to either team until you get an offer from one.

It is possible that they don't know about each other, but it is also possible that they can see the status of the other search. You don't want one of the teams to drop you assuming you will get an offer from the other one.

When one of the teams makes an offer, study it very carefully. You will probably see a requirement that you withdraw from other job searches within that company if you accept the offer. The offer should have an expiration date. They want you to withdraw from the other job search because they don't want a bidding war with themselves.

At this point if you want to see what the other team will offer you, contact them. Tell them that you have an offer from the same company, and when the deadline is. They might drop you, or they could make an offer, or not change their timeline.

If you know you will decline the first offer, if the 2nd team wants to hire you, then you may decide to tell them that. But that still might not get you an offer.

Note: you have no idea which one will make the offer first. I have run into the situation where an offer I was 100% sure was coming because they told me it was a done deal, never materialized.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to contact someone from recruiting or HR within the company to help navigate these waters.  They may be able to manage communications and process across the two teams.

This shouldn't be viewed as the negative that it would be if you were playing two companies against each other.  If you are a good candidate, the company should want you regardless of which team you finally end up with.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that HR has not noticed this already. My HR folks work with the hiring managers and the candidate to make it work as smoothly as possible.

Comment: @JonCuster Given the "different .. geographies", is it possible that there are different HR teams as well?

Comment: @PeterM - conceivable, but it is also conceivable that they have a unified hiring platform (software) that might identify this situation.

Comment: As an applicant, you would hope the company is that connected across locations, but I wouldn't be shocked if no-one is actually looking for some thing like this